# wordpress get taxonomy of a displayed item

Tags: wordpress

I`m writing a wordpress theme. I need to display all parents of the current item that belongs to some taxonomy. The first thing I need to do is to get the taxonomy of the item that is displayed. Here what I tried to do:

```
$id = get_the_ID();
$taxonomy = get_term_by('id', $id)['taxonomy'];
echo 'Current taxonomy is ' . $taxonomy;

$terms = get_the_terms( $id, $taxonomy);
for($i = count( $terms ) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--){
    echo '><a href="' . get_term_link( $terms[$i] ) . '">' . $terms[$i]->name . '</a>';
}
```

The first problem I`ve faced is $taxonomy = "". Please help me.

Comment: please describe your question with taxonomy name and post type name also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$id = get_the_ID();
$taxonomy = get_term_by('id', $id)['taxonomy'];
```

Tou are getting empty $taxonomy because you are trying to get term details using the id of a post and Not the term id. To get the terms associated with the post you have to do this:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy, $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get your terms by `wp_get_post_terms for more information`[click here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms)

Comment: I tried to do     $taxonomy = wp_get_post_terms($id)['taxonomy'];

Comment: , but I can see only Notice: Undefined index: taxonomy in

Comment: why you add ['taxonomy'] in last

Comment: //Returns Array of Term Names for "my_taxonomy"
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($id, 'my_taxonomy', array("fields" => "names"));
print_r($term_list);